# Installing Lightgbm on Mac with OpenMP dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openmpi, lightgbm

I'm new to python and would like to install [lightgbm](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick-Start.html) on my macbook. I did a `pip install lightgbm` and it said installation successful. However when I try to import that into my notebook I get the following error message:

```
../anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
342 
343         if handle is None:
--> 344             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
345         else:
346             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(../anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgomp.1.dylib
Referenced from: ../anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
Reason: image not found
```

The documentation on lightgbm website gives a different installation guideline using `brew install...`. My question is whether I have to do a brew install? If that's the case why the pip installation shows successful installation then?

Comment: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#macos

Comment: I've seen that instruction and question is exacty about that. Why pip install completed successfully?

Comment: Because you need the `open-mpi`, think of Python like the glue and the dependencies are the building materials =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` would only install `lightgbm` python files. The [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#macos) states that `lightgbm` depends on OpenMP. So you need to install that as well. The problem you are facing is because python cannot find the required "dynamic link library" that comes with OpenMP.

`brew install open-mpi` and it should fix the problem.

Sidenote: As a quick test, I installed `lightgbm` the same way you did, and faced the same problem. But I located the `libgopm.1.dylib` in `/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/6`. Symlinking it to the required path didn't prove to be successful.

Comment: how can get 'brew' in the first place?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Source : [brew.sh](http://brew.sh)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS, this worked for me:
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html

macOS
On macOS LightGBM can be built using CMake and Apple Clang or gcc.

**Apple Clang**
Only Apple Clang version 8.1 or higher is supported.

Install CMake (3.12 or higher):

brew install cmake
Install OpenMP:

brew install libomp
Run the following commands:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
mkdir build ; cd build
```

For Mojave (10.14)

```
cmake 
-DOpenMP_C_FLAGS="-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I$(brew --prefix libomp)/include" 
-DOpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES="omp" 
-DOpenMP_CXX_FLAGS="-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I$(brew --prefix libomp)/include" 
-DOpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES="omp" 
-DOpenMP_omp_LIBRARY=$(brew --prefix libomp)/lib/libomp.dylib 
..
```

For High Sierra or earlier (<= 10.13)

```
cmake ..

make -j4
```

**gcc**
Install CMake (3.2 or higher):

```
brew install cmake
```

Install gcc:

```
brew install gcc
```

Run the following commands:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
export CXX=g++-7 CC=gcc-7 # replace "7" with version of gcc installed on your machine
mkdir build ; cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
```

Answer (score 0):

**For MacPorts users:**

Install prerequisite ports:

```
port install cmake gcc7 openmpi-gcc7
```

Install LightGBM with pip:

```
export CXX=g++-mp-7 CC=gcc-mp-7
pip install lightgbm --install-option=--mpi
```

Check other install options like `--gpu` and `--hdfs` in the Python-package installation guide:
https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package