# LightGBM Image Not Found after Mac install

Tags: python, gcc, lightgbm

I installed the lightgbm package with pip (version 10.0.1) to my Python lib (version 3.6.3) on macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6), along with the dependencies found in the [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html), including open-mpi, cmake and gcc.

However, I keep receiving the following exception when I try to import the package using Jupyter notebook (version 5.0.0):

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgomp.1.dylib   
Referenced from: /Users/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so 
Reason: image not found
```

This question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644723/installing-lightgbm-on-mac), but I'm not sure if there was a solution.

**Update**: I had a newer version of GCC (version 8) in the filepath, hence the reason the GCC library was not loaded from path: */usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7*.

It didn't work when I updated the installation script to reflect the latest version (8.1.0) of gcc on my brew install download, as follows:

```
brew install open-mpi
brew install cmake
brew install gcc

git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
export CXX=g++-8 CC=gcc-8  # replace 7 with version of gcc installed on your machine
mkdir build ; cd build
cmake -DUSE_MPI=ON ..
make -j4
```

I had to download version 7 and manually insert it into the local gcc folder.

**Solution**: 
I also followed the solution for a similar problem found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1369).

Answer (score 23):

LightGBM can be installed directly via Homebrew:

```
brew install lightgbm
```

See the [Installation Guide](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html) for more details.

Comment: that seemed to work, I'd suggest accepting answer (or don't but provide feedback)

Answer (score 3):

Installing with conda rather than pip (`conda install lightgbm`) solved this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

ligthGBM can be installed using Homebrew.
first, we need to install homebrew, See a useful youtube video on "how to install homebrew "  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-SDrN4G4lE
When homebrew is installed then
brew install lightgbm

Comment: stackoverflow appreciates that you are providing answers but it would be better if you provide the steps here rather than directing to do from a video, you are always free to suggest a video, but it is always better to help answer seeker to provide direct answers